# Where are the mesh instances used?

Tags: mesh, instances, data-blocks

I don't understand where my other mesh instance is used, I want to have only one instance.

When I click at the number of users (2), I get a single user mesh; but the other mesh still remains even after *Clean up Unused Datablocks*.

My guess is that the two different materials are using one mesh instance each.

[image]

[image: Tree.blend]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the users is the mesh instance itself of course.

The other is a custom property on the object that refers to the mesh instance named "lod_original". Look for it in the Properties editor. If you delete it, the user count drops to 1.

[image: Custom property refers to Tree_Mesh]

(One way to find this out: note that linked-duplicating the object increased the count by 2, so the second user has to be somewhere on the object. Then I just went through the Object section of the Properties editor looking for it.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick answer.